# Motivating Number Theory/Combinatorics questions leading to finite field

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, motivation

I want to learn about Finite Field, but don't want to learn but by starting from the memorizing the axioms of finite field, I wanna learn it by solving a few problems (good if NT /Combinatorics), which statement doesn't involve finite fields, but from which the notion of finite field comes naturally, and then developing the idea by myself.

What are some good such examples of such problems ?

(Note that some people are wrongly interpreting the ASCII art given in bounty text. It's not what you think,  its just a finger pointing upward that I found [here](http://1lineart.kulaone.com/))

Comment: Google polynomial method

Comment: You should learn the axioms for a field intimately so that you know what you are looking for and can recognize a field when you see one.  Also, learning the axioms will not teach you how to find finite fields at all, so that doesn't spoil anything.  Good sources of why you might care are (a) congruences modulo a prime and (b) coordinization of finite geometries.

Comment: Combinatorics you say? Are you familiar with [MOLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square#Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares) (=Mutually Orthogonal Latin Squares)? To construct $p\times p$ MOLS ($p$ a prime) all you need is modular arithmetic. To make the same happen for prime powers, e.g. $4\times4$ or $8\times8$, you need finite fields (but are welcome to try without, if you are into experimenting). Locally, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172606/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Very nice example. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: A field is the structure you need to write $\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b} = \frac{b-a}{ab}$ for any $a,b\ne 0$

Comment: Can you prove that for prime number $ p$ there exists a primitive root modulo $p$? That is, there  exists integer $x$ such that the least $n\in \mathbb N$ for which $x^n\equiv 1 \pmod p$ is $n=p-1.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That's actually a subtly good example (I'm guessing that you're referring to one of the cleanest ways to prove the existence of primitive roots uses the fact that a non-zero polynomial of degree $d$ over a field has at most $d$ roots).

Comment: @ErickWong . That's part of it. Yes. More generally if $\mathbb F=(F,\times,1,+,0)$ is a field and $F$ is finite then the group $\mathbb G=(F$ \  $\{0\}, \times,1)$ is cyclic.

Comment: @Downvoters Care to eggsplane :D ?

Comment: I think that a downvote should be required to be accompanied by an explanation, even if it's anonymous.

Comment: @Wojowu What's polynomial method ?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet OK, Now that I have got a few big hints from a book (PFTB), I can prove that there's a primitive root modulo $p$. So, firstly we prove by induction that a polynomial equation $f(x)$ has $deg[f]$ roots modulo $p$. Then we set $f(x) = x^{d} - 1$, where $p \equiv 1 \mod d$. Now, we use $\sum_{d | p-1} \phi(d) = p-1$ to prove a inequality is infact an equality, so there are exactly $\phi(d)$ elements with order $d$ modulo $p$, where $d | p-1$. Could you give a hint how this leads to finite field ?

Comment: Arithmetic mod $ p$ on $\Bbb Z$  $is$  a finite  field, which is elementary.  We can prove the general result that if $F$ is a finite field then multiplication on the non-zero members of $F$ is a  $cyclic$ group, and obtain the primitive root mod $p$ as an immediate corollary.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the question that in fact got me interested in finite fields:

> How does the Fibonacci sequence behave $\bmod p$, for $p$ a prime?

In particular, here are two exercises. Suppose $p \neq 5$. Let $\left( \frac{5}{p} \right)$ denote the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), which, as it turns out, is equal to $1$ if $p \equiv 1, 4 \bmod 5$ and $-1$ if $p \equiv 2, 3 \bmod 5$.

> **Exercise 1:** Show that $F_p \equiv \left( \frac{5}{p} \right) \bmod p$.
>
> **Exercise 2:** Show that $F_{p - \left( \frac{5}{p} \right)} \equiv 0 \bmod p$.

Comment: I think you meant $(\frac{5}{p}) \equiv 5^{(p-1)/2} \bmod p$ where $F_p \equiv (\frac{5}{p}) \bmod p$ follows from expressing $F_p$ in term of [powers of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Showing $(\frac{5}{p}) = (\frac{p}{5})$ needs more [work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_using_Quadratic_Gauss_Sums) ($\sqrt{5} = \sum_{n=0}^4 \zeta_5^{n^2}$)

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering ! By $F_p$,
you mean the p th Fiboancci number, not finite field, right ? (Also, sorry for promoting, but do you have any answer for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422528/why-should-i-care-about-proving-a-polynomial-to-be-irreducible ? )

Comment: Yes, otherwise the statements wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

The following problem is from Babai and Frankl's textbook on linear algebra methods in combinatorics.  One of the motivating factors of fields in general is that they support all the operations needed to perform linear algebra, which means that we can apply the concepts of rank and linear independence to vectors over a finite field.

There is a town of $n$ people who form clubs (each club being just a set of townspeople) according to the following rules:

1. The number of members of any given club must be **odd** (i.e. every set has odd cardinality).
2. Given any two different clubs, the number of people they have in common must be **even** (i.e. intersections have even cardinality).

What is the maximum number of clubs that can be formed while conforming to these rules?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I found the unexpected application of finite field in the following problem about sum-free sets by Paul Erdös:

> **Theorem.** (Erdös) A set of integers $B$ is call a sum-free set if for any $x,y \in B$ then $x+y \not\in B$. Prove that for any set of nonzero integers $A$, there is a sum-free subset $B \subseteq A$ of size $|B|>\frac 13 |A|$.

The theorem's statement has no connection to finite field. Surprisingly, the proof for this uses [probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) combining with working in $\mathbf{Z}_p$.